# Matching arrays in Scala

Tags: scala

In this example code I need to print each `Seq`, problem is that when I match it I only have one variable `x` instead of an array. How to get the array? Moreover, this code only prints `do nothing` twice.

```
   var seq = Seq(Seq(1,2,3),Seq(4,5,6))
   seq.foreach { seq2 =>
     seq2 match {
       case Seq(x) => println(x)
       case _ => println("do nothing")
     }
   }
```

Comment: Did you mean `case s: Seq[_] => println(s)`? That's not very clean though, because you already know that `seq` is `Seq[Seq[Int]]`, it seems that there is no need for a `match-case` at all?

Comment: Your code would only print the sequence if it has only 1 element; try with `Seq(Seq(1), Seq(4, 5, 6))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a homogeneous `Seq[Seq[Int]]`, you don't have to match at all:

```
var seq = Seq(Seq(1,2,3),Seq(4,5,6))
seq foreach println
```

If you have a sequence of mixed elements like this:

```
var seq = Seq[Any](Seq(1,2,3), 42)
```

then you can match by `type` `Seq`, which is equivalent to an `isInstanceOf`. In this case, you will have to add a `_` for the erased type of `Seq`:

```
seq.foreach { seq2 =>
  seq2 match {
    case s: Seq[_] => println(s)
    case _ => println("do nothing")
  }
}
```

You should avoid the second variant. It would be preferable to create a custom sealed trait with case classes and do the pattern matching properly:

```
sealed trait ValidSeqContent
case class IntInSeq(i: Int) extends ValidSeqContent
case class SeqOfIntsInSeq(seq: Seq[Int]) extends ValidSeqContent

val seq: Seq[ValidSeqContent] = Seq(
  SeqOfIntsInSeq(Seq(1,2,3)),
  IntInSeq(42)
)
```

Then you can do pattern matching without `isInstanceOf`-like matches:

```
seq.foreach{ x =>
  x match {
    case SeqOfIntsInSeq(s) => println(s)
    case _ => { /* do nothing */ }
  }
}
```